# is there extension to know if the invoice has been printed or not?

Tags: magento-1.9

I am using Magento 1 and I am looking for an extension to tell me whether an invoice has been printed or not. For avoid order duplicated or missing to print.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without an extension - In `System > Order Statuses` create a custom status called 'Printed' and set it to be Processing state. When you print an invoice set the status of the order to be 'Printed'.